# reading the serializable objects from file

Tags: java, file, deserialization

```
 List ll=new LinkedList();
 Student temp;

 int size = obj.readInt();
 System.out.println(size);
 for (int i = 0; i <size; ++i) {
        ll.add((Student) obj.readObject());
 }

 obj.close();
     System.out.println(ll);
 }
```

it causes the run time exception as
    `"Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException`

```
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
at p1.DeSerializeDemo1.main(DeSerializeDemo1.java:18)"
```

Please give me solution for this.

Comment: How are you writing the object in file.Paste that code too

Comment: Student st=new Student();
 st.setSno(101);
 st.setSname("deva");
 st.setMarks(78.4f);
 
 Student st1=new Student();
 st1.setSno(102);
 st1.setSname("raju");
 st1.setMarks(80.56f);
 
 FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("student.txt");
 ObjectOutputStream obj=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
 obj.writeObject(st1);
 obj.writeObject(st);

Comment: Edit your question, don't paste in coments

Comment: You don't have to use readInt(). Just check 'obj.hasNext()' if its `true`, read the object  using `obj.readObject();`.

Comment: i have written some code. I think it is of your concern . Check [this](http://ideone.com/sG7zeP)

Answer (score 0):

Just handle the `Exception`

```
try{
      int size = obj.readInt();
 }catch(EOFException ex){}
```

Comment: is there any method like `obj.hasNext()` in ObjectInputStream class ?

Answer (score 0):

`EOFException` in `ObjectInputStream.readInt` means that there are less than 4 bytes left in the file after current position.

Comment: He's not writing any `int` into the file.Don't know why is he trying to `readInt()`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a class and save/load the entire object (that class needs to implement Serializable though (and all objects used it that class too)), then get the information you want using that object you can cast it afterwards:

```
public static Object load(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, Exception {
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path))) {
        final Object result = ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        return result;
    }
}

public static void save(Object obj, String path) throws Exception {
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path))) {
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception cause is that you are not calling `ObjectOutputStream.writeInt(int)` before writing objects. As far as I understand you are trying to store number of objects, which is stored in the file. So, you should do it like this: `obj.writeInt(2);`

```
public class Test implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 243705916609512381L;

    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test s = new Test();
        s.setName("Test");
        Test s1 = new Test();
        s1.setName("Test 2");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\test.txt");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            oos.writeInt(2);
            oos.writeObject(s1);
            oos.writeObject(s);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();

            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\test.txt");
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            int readInt = ois.readInt();
            System.out.println("Read int " + readInt);
            Test readObject = (Test) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(readObject.getName());
            Test readObject2 = (Test) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(readObject2.getName());
            ois.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // close everything
        }
    }
```